# Btrieve GetNextExtended 'UC' Option Returning Only One Record Repeatedly

Tags: vb6, btrieve

I am working on Pervasive SQL 2000i SP4 and accessing my data via the Btrieve API.
Recently I delved into the *GetNextExtended* operation and using the 'EG' option, but the first record in was always ignored. To take the first record into account as well I decided to switch to the 'UC' option, but this resulted in the same record being returned repeatedly. The databuffer I generate contain no 'Terms'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
'Form1 - just a form with one button on it

Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
   (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)


Private Sub Command_Click()
    GetAllRecords
End Sub


Private Sub GetAllRecords()
    Dim boolContinueLoop As Boolean
    Dim objBtrvAPI As clsBtrvAPI

    Set objBtrvAPI = New clsBtrvAPI
    objBtrvAPI.OpenConnection "C:\Pastel09\_Demo\accrecpt.dat"

    objBtrvAPI.GetFirst

    boolContinueLoop = True

    Do
        objBtrvAPI.Record = GenerateGetNextExtendedDataBuffer()
        objBtrvAPI.GetNextExtended

        If (Not objBtrvAPI.EOF) Then
            'Read record - not necessary for this test
        End If

        boolContinueLoop = (Not objBtrvAPI.EOF)
    Loop Until Not boolContinueLoop

    objBtrvAPI.CloseConnection
    Set objBtrvAPI = Nothing
End Sub


Private Function GenerateGetNextExtendedDataBuffer() As Byte()
    Dim intRecordImageLength As Integer
    Dim bytDataBuffer() As Byte
    Dim intDataBufferElementCount As Integer
    Dim intNoOfLeadingBytesReturnedByExtendedOp As Integer

    intRecordImageLength = 94

    ReDim bytDataBuffer(0)

    AddIntToByteArray bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, 0                       'Total data buffer size - placeholder, value will be assigned later
    AddStringToByteArray bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, "UC"                 'Begin with the current record
    AddIntToByteArray bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, 0                       'Max Reject Count
    AddIntToByteArray bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, 0                       'Number Of Terms

    AddIntToByteArray bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, 1                       'Number of records to retrieve
    AddIntToByteArray bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, 1                       'Number of fields to extract
    AddIntToByteArray bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, intRecordImageLength    'Field length - select the entire record in one field
    AddIntToByteArray bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, 0                       'Field offset/position

    'Eight bytes are returned on the GetNextExtended call
    '2 bytes - number of records returned - at present only one record is returned at one time
    '2 bytes - length of the record image
    '4 bytes - a pointer to the record
    intNoOfLeadingBytesReturnedByExtendedOp = 8

    SetLeadingBytesToIndicateSize bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount

    If (intDataBufferElementCount < intRecordImageLength + intNoOfLeadingBytesReturnedByExtendedOp) Then
        MakeSize bytDataBuffer, intDataBufferElementCount, intRecordImageLength + intNoOfLeadingBytesReturnedByExtendedOp
    End If

    GenerateGetNextExtendedDataBuffer = bytDataBuffer
End Function


Public Sub AddIntToByteArray(ByRef pbytDataBuffer() As Byte, _
                             ByRef pintElementCount As Integer, _
                             ByVal pintValue As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim byteValue() As Byte

    byteValue = ConvertIntToByteArray(pintValue)

    pintElementCount = pintElementCount + 2
    ReDim Preserve pbytDataBuffer(pintElementCount - 1)

    For i = 1 To 0 Step -1
        pbytDataBuffer(pintElementCount - 1 - i) = byteValue(1 - i)
    Next i
End Sub


Public Sub AddStringToByteArray(ByRef pbytDataBuffer() As Byte, _
                                ByRef pintElementCount As Integer, _
                                ByVal pstrValue As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strValueToConvert As String
    Dim byteValue() As Byte

    pintElementCount = pintElementCount + Len(pstrValue)
    ReDim Preserve pbytDataBuffer(pintElementCount - 1)

    strValueToConvert = StrReverse(pstrValue)

    For i = Len(pstrValue) To 1 Step -1
        pbytDataBuffer(pintElementCount - i) = Asc(Mid$(strValueToConvert, i, 1))
    Next i
End Sub


Private Sub MakeSize(ByRef pbytDataBuffer() As Byte, _
                     ByRef pintElementCount As Integer, _
                     ByVal pintSize As Integer)
    pintElementCount = pintSize
    ReDim Preserve pbytDataBuffer(pintElementCount - 1)
End Sub


Private Sub SetLeadingBytesToIndicateSize(ByRef pbytDataBuffer() As Byte, _
                                          ByRef pintElementCount As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim byteSize() As Byte

    byteSize = ConvertIntToByteArray(pintElementCount)

    For i = 0 To UBound(byteSize)
        pbytDataBuffer(i) = byteSize(i)
    Next i
End Sub


Private Function ConvertIntToByteArray(ByVal pintValue As Integer) As Byte()
    Dim byteArray(0 To 1) As Byte

    CopyMemory byteArray(0), ByVal VarPtr(pintValue), Len(pintValue)
    ConvertIntToByteArray = byteArray
End Function


'clsBtrvAPI

Option Explicit

Private Const KEY_BUFFER_LEN = 255

'Btrieve operations
Private Const B_OPEN = 0
Private Const B_CLOSE = 1
Private Const B_GETFIRST = 12
Private Const B_STAT = 15
Private Const B_GETNEXTEXTENDED = 36

Private Declare Function BTRCALL Lib "wbtrv32.dll" (ByVal OpCode As Integer, PositionBlock As Any, DataBuffer As Any, _
                                                    DataLength As Long, KeyBuffer As Any, ByVal KeyLength As Integer, _
                                                    ByVal KeyNumber As Integer) As Integer

Private Type TypePositionBlock
    PosBlk(128) As Byte
End Type

Private Type TypeOwner
    Owner As String * 8
End Type

Private Type TypeKeySpec
    KeyPos As Integer
    KeyLen As Integer
    KeyFlags As Integer
    KeyTot As String * 4
    KeyType As String * 1
    Reserved As String * 5
End Type

Private Type TypeStatFileSpecs
    RecLen As Integer
    PageSize As Integer
    IndexTot As Integer
    RecTot As String * 4
    FileFlags As Integer
    Reserved As String * 2
    UnusedPages As Integer
    KeyBuf(0 To 119) As TypeKeySpec
End Type

Private m_strDataFilePath As String
Private m_byteFilePosBlk As TypePositionBlock
Private m_boolFileOpen As Boolean
Private m_boolEOF As Boolean
Private m_byteRecordBuffer() As Byte

Private m_intKeyNum As Integer


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_strDataFilePath = ""
    m_boolFileOpen = False
    m_boolEOF = True
    m_intKeyNum = 0
End Sub


Private Function GetRecordLen() As Integer
    Dim typeStat As TypeStatFileSpecs
    Dim strKeyBuffer As String
    Dim lngDataBufferLen As Long
    Dim intKeyBufferLen As Integer
    Dim intStatus As Integer

    lngDataBufferLen = Len(typeStat)
    strKeyBuffer = Space$(KEY_BUFFER_LEN)
    intKeyBufferLen = KEY_BUFFER_LEN

    intStatus = BTRCALL(B_STAT, m_byteFilePosBlk, typeStat, lngDataBufferLen, _
                        ByVal strKeyBuffer, KEY_BUFFER_LEN, 0)

    If (intStatus = 0) Then
        'Successfull
        GetRecordLen = typeStat.RecLen
    End If
End Function


Public Sub CloseConnection()
    Dim intStatus As Integer

    intStatus = BTRCALL(B_CLOSE, m_byteFilePosBlk, "", 0, 0, 0, 0)

    If (intStatus = 0) Then
        m_boolFileOpen = False
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub GetFirst(Optional ByVal pintKey As Integer = 0)
    Dim lngDataBufferLen As Long
    Dim strKeyBuffer As String
    Dim intKeyBufferLen As Integer
    Dim intStatus As Integer

    If (m_boolFileOpen) Then
        lngDataBufferLen = UBound(m_byteRecordBuffer)
        strKeyBuffer = Space$(KEY_BUFFER_LEN)
        intKeyBufferLen = KEY_BUFFER_LEN

        intStatus = BTRCALL(B_GETFIRST, m_byteFilePosBlk, m_byteRecordBuffer(1), lngDataBufferLen, _
                            ByVal strKeyBuffer, intKeyBufferLen, pintKey)

        If (intStatus = 0) Then
            m_intKeyNum = pintKey
            m_boolEOF = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub GetNextExtended()
    Dim lngDataBufferLen As Long
    Dim strKeyBuffer As String
    Dim intStatus As Integer

    If (m_boolFileOpen) Then
        lngDataBufferLen = UBound(m_byteRecordBuffer) + 1
        strKeyBuffer = Space$(KEY_BUFFER_LEN)

        intStatus = BTRCALL(B_GETNEXTEXTENDED, m_byteFilePosBlk, m_byteRecordBuffer(0), lngDataBufferLen, _
                            ByVal strKeyBuffer, Len(strKeyBuffer), m_intKeyNum)

        If (intStatus = 9 Or intStatus = 64) Then
            m_boolEOF = True
        Else
            If (intStatus = 0) Then
                m_boolEOF = False
            Else
                Debug.Assert False
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub OpenConnection(Optional ByVal pstrDataFilePath As String)
    Dim typeDataBuffer As TypeOwner
    Dim strKeyBuffer As String
    Dim lngDataBufferLen As Long
    Dim intStatus As Integer

    typeDataBuffer.Owner = ""
    m_strDataFilePath = pstrDataFilePath

    lngDataBufferLen = Len(typeDataBuffer)
    strKeyBuffer = Chr(34) & m_strDataFilePath & Chr(34)

    intStatus = BTRCALL(B_OPEN, _
                        m_byteFilePosBlk, _
                        typeDataBuffer, _
                        lngDataBufferLen, _
                        ByVal strKeyBuffer, _
                        KEY_BUFFER_LEN, _
                        0)

    If (intStatus = 0) Then
        m_boolFileOpen = True
        ReDim m_byteRecordBuffer(1 To GetRecordLen)
    End If
End Sub


Public Property Get DataFilePath() As String
    DataFilePath = m_strDataFilePath
End Property

Public Property Let DataFilePath(ByVal pstrValue As String)
    m_strDataFilePath = pstrValue
End Property


Public Property Get EOF() As Boolean
    EOF = m_boolEOF
End Property


Public Property Get Record() As Byte()
    Record = m_byteRecordBuffer
End Property

Public Property Let Record(ByRef pbytValue() As Byte)
    m_byteRecordBuffer = pbytValue
End Property
```

Here is an excerpt of the MKDE trace log where the 'UC' option is used which 
results in the same record being returned repeatedly:

```
MicroKernel Database Engine [Workstation Edition] for Windows NT/95/98 
trace file
Created : 24 January 2011 16:04:28

<In> 0001   Opcode : 0026   Crs ID : 0xffffffff  Db Length : 00005   
Keynum : ff   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d19  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  00 00 00 00 00          -                           .....           
KBuf:  ??                      -                           .               

<Out>0001   Status : 0000   Crs ID : 0xffffffff  Db Length : 00005   
Keynum : ff   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d19  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  07 00 5a 00 39          -                           ..Z.9           
KBuf:  ??                      -                           .               

---------------------------------------------------------------------
<In> 0002   Opcode : 0000   Crs ID : 0xffffffff  Db Length : 00008   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d1a  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  4e 4f 54 53 48 4f 57 4e - 00                        NOTSHOWN.       
KBuf:  43 3a 5c 50 61 73 74 65 - 6c 30 39 5c 5f 44 65 6d   C:\Pastel09\_Dem
       6f 5c 61 63 63 72 65 63 - 70 74 2e 64 61 74 00 00   o\accrecpt.dat..
       00 00 00 0c bd 06 d4 84 - 6b 3e 3a 47 ac 10 5e 78   ....½.Ô„k>:G¬.^x
File:  "C:\Pastel09\_Demo\accrecpt.dat"

<Out>0002   Status : 0000   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00008   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d1d  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  4e 4f 54 53 48 4f 57 4e - 00                        NOTSHOWN.       
KBuf:  43 3a 5c 50 61 73 74 65 - 6c 30 39 5c 5f 44 65 6d   C:\Pastel09\_Dem
       6f 5c 61 63 63 72 65 63 - 70 74 2e 64 61 74 00 00   o\accrecpt.dat..
       00 00 00 0c 43 4f 4d 50 - 32 5c 50 69 65 74 69 65   ....COMP2\Pietie

---------------------------------------------------------------------
<In> 0003   Opcode : 0015   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00028   
Keynum : fe   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d1d  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  00 00 d3 01 fe ff ff ff - 1e 23 9e 77 30 00 b0 01   ..Ó.þÿÿÿ.#žw0.°.
       e8 cc 01 66 00 00 00 00 - 88 fe e9 05               èÌ.f.....þé.    
KBuf:  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 - 88 fe e9 05 1c 00 00 00   .........þé.....
       60 fe e9 05 00 00 b0 01 - 22 00 c9 01 00 00 00 00   `þé...°.".É.....
       a4 03 00 00 b8 fe e9 01 - 68 00 b0 01 ff ff ff ff   ¤...¸þé.h.°.ÿÿÿÿ
       00 00 1a 00 08 00 00 00 - 00 07 db 4a 4d 81 4d 51   ..........ÛJM.MQ
       00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ....ÿÿÿÿ........
       00 00 f4 0c 57 52 f4 0c - ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ..ô.WRô.ÿ.......
       8c 5e 9d 77 9c 17 bb 75 - 9c 03 00 00 00 00 00 00   Œ^.wœ.»uœ.......
       c4 17 bb 75 72 59 c5 fb - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   Ä.»urYÅû........

<Out>0003   Status : 0000   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00013   
Keynum : fe   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d1d  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  09 00 80 03 09 0d 10 08 - 0c 0c 0c 01 0a            .............   
KBuf:  00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 - 88 fe e9 05 0d 00 00 00   .........þé.....
       60 fe e9 05 00 00 b0 01 - 22 00 c9 01 00 00 00 00   `þé...°.".É.....
       a4 03 00 00 b8 fe e9 01 - 68 00 b0 01 ff ff ff ff   ¤...¸þé.h.°.ÿÿÿÿ
       00 00 1a 00 08 00 00 00 - 00 07 db 4a 4d 81 4d 51   ..........ÛJM.MQ
       00 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ....ÿÿÿÿ........
       00 00 f4 0c 57 52 f4 0c - ff 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ..ô.WRô.ÿ.......
       8c 5e 9d 77 9c 17 bb 75 - 9c 03 00 00 00 00 00 00   Œ^.wœ.»uœ.......
       c4 17 bb 75 72 59 c5 fb - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   Ä.»urYÅû........

---------------------------------------------------------------------
<In> 0004   Opcode : 0015   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 01936   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d1e  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  33 00 cb ff ff ff ff ff - ff ff ff ff ff ff ff 00   3.Ëÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ.
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 80 03 09 0d 10 08 0c   ................
       0c 0c 01 0a 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 20 20 20 20 20 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ...     ........
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
KBuf:                               -                                           

<Out>0004   Status : 0000   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00352   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d1e  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  80 03 00 04 09 00 04 00 - 00 00 00 03 03 00 00 00   ................
       05 00 08 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       0d 00 01 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       0d 00 01 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00   ................
       01 00 04 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00   ................
       05 00 08 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00   ................
       05 00 08 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00   ................
       14 00 01 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00   ................
       15 00 07 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00   ................
       14 00 01 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00   ................
       15 00 07 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00   ................
       01 00 04 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 01 00 00 00 04 00   ................
       05 00 08 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00   ................
       14 00 01 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00   ................
       15 00 07 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00   ................
       01 00 04 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00   ................
KBuf:                               -                                           

---------------------------------------------------------------------
<In> 0005   Opcode : 0012   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00896   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d1f  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  80 03 00 04 09 00 04 00 - 00 00 00 03 03 00 00 00   ................
       05 00 08 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       0d 00 01 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       0d 00 01 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00   ................
       01 00 04 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 01 00 00 00 01 00   ................
       05 00 08 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00   ................
       05 00 08 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00   ................
       14 00 01 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00   ................
       15 00 07 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00   ................
       14 00 01 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00   ................
       15 00 07 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00   ................
       01 00 04 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 01 00 00 00 04 00   ................
       05 00 08 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00   ................
       14 00 01 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00   ................
       15 00 07 00 13 01 04 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 05 00   ................
       01 00 04 00 03 01 04 00 - 00 00 01 00 00 00 05 00   ................
KBuf:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00                        .........       

<Out>0005   Status : 0000   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00896   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 00009d1f  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:28 2011
DBuf:  01 00 00 00 52 43 31 30 - 30 30 30 31 01 05 41 42   ....RC100001..AB
       43 44 45 44 41 41 41 41 - 41 41 41 67 00 1b 05 d8   CDEDAAAAAAAg...Ø
       07 00 46 69 72 73 74 20 - 45 6e 74 72 79 20 20 20   ..First Entry   
       20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                   
       20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00             ......
       00 00 59 40 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 24 40 00 00 00 00   ..Y@......$@....
       00 c0 72 40 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   .Àr@............
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 41 6c 62 6f   ............Albo
       74 74 20 4c 69 6d 69 74 - 65 64 20 20 20 20 20 20   tt Limited      
       20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                   
       20 20 20 20 31 34 2f 33 - 33 20 4f 66 66 69 63 65       14/33 Office
       20 43 72 65 73 63 65 6e - 74 20 20 20 20 20 20 20    Crescent       
KBuf:  52 43 31 30 30 30 30 31 - 01                        RC100001.       

---------------------------------------------------------------------
<In> 0006   Opcode : 0036   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00102   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 0000ad9b  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:32 2011
DBuf:  10 00 55 43 00 00 00 00 - 01 00 01 00 5e 00 00 00   ..UC........^...
       41 41 67 00 1b 05 d8 07 - 00 46 69 72 73 74 20 45   AAg...Ø..First E
       6e 74 72 79 20 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   ntry            
       20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                   
       20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 59 40 00 00 00 00 00    ........Y@.....
       00 24 40 00 00 00 00 00 - c0 72 40 00 00 00 00 00   .$@.....Àr@.....
       00 00 00 00 00 00       -                           ......          
KBuf:  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20                                        

<Out>0006   Status : 0000   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00102   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 0000ad9c  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:32 2011
DBuf:  01 00 5e 00 00 0b 00 00 - 01 00 00 00 52 43 31 30   ..^.........RC10
       30 30 30 31 01 05 41 42 - 43 44 45 44 41 41 41 41   0001..ABCDEDAAAA
       41 41 41 67 00 1b 05 d8 - 07 00 46 69 72 73 74 20   AAAg...Ø..First 
       45 6e 74 72 79 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   Entry           
       20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                   
       20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 59 40 00 00 00 00     ........Y@....
       00 00 24 40 00 00       -                           ..$@..          
KBuf:  52 43 31 30 30 30 30 31 - 01                        RC100001.       

---------------------------------------------------------------------
<In> 0007   Opcode : 0036   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00102   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 0000b345  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:34 2011
DBuf:  10 00 55 43 00 00 00 00 - 01 00 01 00 5e 00 00 00   ..UC........^...
       30 30 30 31 01 05 41 42 - 43 44 45 44 41 41 41 41   0001..ABCDEDAAAA
       41 41 41 67 00 1b 05 d8 - 07 00 46 69 72 73 74 20   AAAg...Ø..First 
       45 6e 74 72 79 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   Entry           
       20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                   
       20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 59 40 00 00 00 00     ........Y@....
       00 00 24 40 00 00       -                           ..$@..          
KBuf:  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20                                        

<Out>0007   Status : 0000   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00102   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 0000b345  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:34 2011
DBuf:  01 00 5e 00 00 0b 00 00 - 01 00 00 00 52 43 31 30   ..^.........RC10
       30 30 30 31 01 05 41 42 - 43 44 45 44 41 41 41 41   0001..ABCDEDAAAA
       41 41 41 67 00 1b 05 d8 - 07 00 46 69 72 73 74 20   AAAg...Ø..First 
       45 6e 74 72 79 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20   Entry           
       20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 - 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20                   
       20 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 59 40 00 00 00 00     ........Y@....
       00 00 24 40 00 00       -                           ..$@..          
KBuf:  52 43 31 30 30 30 30 31 - 01                        RC100001.       

---------------------------------------------------------------------
<In> 0012   Opcode : 0001   Crs ID : 0x00010000  Db Length : 00000   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 0000d735  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:43 2011
DBuf:       ??                      -                           .               
KBuf:       ??                      -                           .               

<Out>0012   Status : 0000   Crs ID : 0x00000000  Db Length : 00000   
Keynum : 00   Clnt ID : 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 F4 0C 57 52 F4 0C  
Clock : 0000d737  Time : Mon Jan 24 16:04:43 2011
DBuf:       ??                      -                           .               
KBuf:       ??                      -                           .               

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Just a note on the trace log, from transaction 0008 to 0011 all the data is excactly the 
same as 0007 so those entries were left out for some much needed brevity. After 0011 I stopped the loop manually since it would just keep on returning the same record indefinitely.

Comment: If you specify the UC option, you should get all of the records that match the filter including the current record.  

You might want to turn on MKDE tracing to make sure that the GetNextExtended call is being sent the way you think it's being sent.  
Also, you might want to post your code that creates the GetNextExtended buffer.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I included a part of the trace log in my question. Something that I did pick up was that when using the 'EG' option as described, the trace log actually four entries for the GetNextExtended(36) operation which returns with a successful status(0). Somehow I am missing one of those operations in my app. I'll keep snooping around.

Comment: Can you increase the Data Buffer size in the MKDE tracing to at least 128?  This will let us see the whole return buffer.  

Also, can you post the code you're using to populate the buffer that's going into the GetNextExtended?

Comment: The Data Buffer size was already set to 128. I set it to 256 but there was no notable difference. I'm only returning the first 96 bytes of the record, so it makes sense that the Data Buffer isn't that large.

Comment: I added a code sample. I hope you can follow what is happening without seeing the entire source. Let me know if something isn't clear enough.

Comment: I guess I'm really confused at this point.  The MKDE trace shows a "UC" operation but the code you posted shows an "EG" call with only one record returned.  Looking at the trace, I see one record in the return buffer.  
WHen I mentioned about increasing the databuffer size to 128, I meant in the MKDE tracing options not in the Btrieve call itself.  
At this point, here's what I would suggest: Create a simple app that only opens the file, does the GetFirst, then a GetNextExtended.  Run with tracing turned on and make sure no other applications are running.  Post the full code and MKDE trace.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've been jumping between 'UC' and 'EG' to find a solution, trying to solve two different problems at the same time, so I restructured my question to focus on the 'UC' problem. I included the source of a simple test app and most of the trace log. I only omitted a few entries that were exact duplicates. As far as the databuffer size is concerned I understood that you were referring to the MKDE tracing option and I set it in the Pervasive Control Centre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, now I see the problem.  Since you have the number of records to return set to 1, you will only get 1 record.  Because you have it set for "UC", it will start with the current record and return one record... the same record, no matter how many times you run the code.
There is no magical "return all records in the table" in the GetNextExtended.  You'll need to set the "number of records to return" to the number of records that will fit in approximately 62K.  The maximum is really 64K minus some overhead.  There's actually a formula in the PSQL documentation.  Also, the "UC" option should only be used the first time GNE is called.  After that, switch it to "EG" so it progresses down the records.  You would continue with the GNE calls until status 9 (end of file) is returned.

Comment: Using 'UC' for the first call and 'EG' for subsequent calls did the trick. I'll have to look into returning more than one record per call. Would returning multiple records per call be much better for performance?

Comment: I did a few tests and found that returning the maximum number of records per call on a table of about 250,000 records is much, much faster. Almost 100x faster in fact.

Comment: As you've found, returning multiple records can have a significant performance improvement.  The GNE was added to Btrieve to improve performance when reading multiple records.  It also reduces network traffic by only sending one request to the server and only getting one response back. 
Glad it's working for you now.